# Retrieve the ListItem index in Google Doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, listitem

In Google Apps Script (Google Document), when a `ListItem` is set to `DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER`, how can I retrieve the `ListItem` number?

**Note**: The `ListItem` objects may not be consecutives, and they may not have the same parent.

**Context:**

Google Doc has the ability to create numbered lists starting at any index:

- Type "3."
- Press space

--> a new list starting with 3 will be created.

I need to retrieve that number in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to find out this information. Please file an enhancement request for this feature at the [Apps Script issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list).

Comment: the issue was logged here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3678&thanks=3678&ts=1416929856